# Set ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute to GET/POST for same action MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

My question is very straight forward...

I have an `Action` which accepts both `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`, but I want to set `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute to the action when the http request is `POST`, not for `HttpGet`.

I can find whether the request is `GET` or `POST` inside the action, but I need to know before the action called.

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  // Only for HttpPost
    public ActionResult Index() // Allows HttpPost / HttpGet
    {

    }
```

Is there any possibilities to achieve this without duplicating the action?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could conditionally check the request's HTTP method and manually do the validation yourself:

```
if (Request.Method.ToLower() == "post") 
{
    System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();
}
```

Comment: works, though used if (Request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post) instead for the if statement as Request.Method didn't exist in the controller

Answer (score 3):

First off, this is a very bad design. The point of MVC is to separate methods in the controller. If you want two methods to have the same behavior, I suggest amending your controller to have a GET and a POST that each call the same method elsewhere in the controller.

But you could write a Validation attribute to accomplish what you want.

Based on this [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.cs), you could edit the `OnAuthorization` method in the Validation attribute to:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;
        if (request != "GET")
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            ValidateAction();
        }
    }
```

which now checks to see if the request is `GET` in which case it skips the validation. The full Attribute class is:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute2 : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private string _salt;

    public ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute2()
        : this(AntiForgery.Validate)
    {
    }

    internal ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute2(Action validateAction)
    {
        Debug.Assert(validateAction != null);
        ValidateAction = validateAction;
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA2204:Literals should be spelled correctly", MessageId = "AdditionalDataProvider", Justification = "API name.")]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA2204:Literals should be spelled correctly", MessageId = "AntiForgeryConfig", Justification = "API name.")]
    [Obsolete("The 'Salt' property is deprecated. To specify custom data to be embedded within the token, use the static AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider property.", error: true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string Salt
    {
        get { return _salt; }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The 'Salt' property is deprecated. To specify custom data to be embedded within the token, use the static AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider property.");
            }
            _salt = value;
        }
    }

    internal Action ValidateAction { get; private set; }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;
        if (request != "GET")
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            ValidateAction();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing already built into the framework that would currently allow you to do this but you still have one option. Create your own implementation of [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs(v=vs.118).aspx) that takes a parameter the [http verb/actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs(v=vs.118).aspx) that you want it to validate on. The easiest way is to implement interface `IAuthorizationFilter`.

Comment: @lgor, Thank you for your quick response. But I got more better solution which I marked as an answer.

Comment: @Shanthini - its a good answer and easy to implement BUT if you need to do this on many methods then writing the code once in a custom `Filter` is a better and more maintainable solution than adding the above `if` statement to all of your methods.

Comment: @lgor Yes. I agree.  But at the moment I had this issue in only one scenario :) But I did create a custom filter for future reference; not using it now.

Answer (score 1):

You have possibility to detect this [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914648/detect-if-action-is-a-post-or-get-method):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
{
    // The action is a POST.
}
```

and you need a method attribute to intercept before run action and take different  behavior to skip action. The `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is not run on `GET` [Using MVC3's AntiForgeryToken in HTTP GET to avoid Javascript CSRF vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914994/using-mvc3s-antiforgerytoken-in-http-get-to-avoid-javascript-csrf-vulnerability).